# HTML text input not showing in Droid

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, textinput

For some reason, on a Droid, my `<input type="text">` field is not showing correctly. It does not show the user what is typed until the user moves on to the next field. 
I checked on some online forums and it seems that this may be a Droid internal issue. However, despite that, is there any way around it? (Note: I'm using bootstrap.js and the input field is inheriting CSS styles from it. Not sure if bootstrap plays nicely with Droid?)

Here's my HTML input fields (not sure if it matters):

```
<label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
<input type="text" class="requiredInput" name="firstName" value="">
<label for="lastName" class="">Last Name*</label>
<input type="text" class="requiredInput" name="lastName" value="">
```

Here's the CSS that applies to an  field, apart from the bootstrap.js CSS:

```
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 4px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
```

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all CSS styles except margin-bottom (so that it became a very plain-looking input field) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to decrease padding top and padding bottom